# android volley does not receive php json object

Tags: json, android-volley

I'm using android volley for send request to server side, in the other hand on server side I use php.
Here is my android code to receive response from server(does not matter what params is, because I do not need params on server side yet!):

```
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ATA d Response", response.toString());
                        VolleyLog.v("ATA Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ATA Response", " RESPONSE ERROR");
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    req.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.getCache().clear();
    queue.add(req);
```

Now, when in server side i return as response something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST)) {    
    echo json_encode(array("x"=>"y", "m"=>"n"));
    exit();
}
```

every this is ok, and response is what server sends!

But! when in server side I return as response something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST)) {    
    echo json_encode(array(array("0"=>"1"),array("2"=>"3"),array("4"=>"5")));
    exit();
}
```

Response is not ok and get this error:

```
06-17 02:28:53.456  D/Volley: [1296] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] MY_URL 0xa64d9c1b NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3645], [size=60], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]

06-17 02:28:53.466  D/ATA Response:  RESPONSE ERROR

06-17 02:28:53.466  E/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: add  json format your are sending json in array and get in object may make array request get json...

Comment: @nEwDeV please clarify what you said, did not get that!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a content type header. `application/json` should do the job.

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
```

send header before producing any outputs (i.e before `echo` statement).